# Enter python code in the cli

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a shortcut where I do a `git pull` and then run a script. Is there any way to do the following?

```
$ git pull origin production && print 'hello'
```

I don't want to do the `$ python -c 'print "hello"'` but actually want to enter it into the python shell.

This is what I'm looking to do in one line in the shell:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~/Avails$ git pull origin production
From github.com:sideways/Avails
 * branch            production -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/Avails$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'hello'
hello
```

Comment: Is pygit2 not a solution?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh that's pretty neat I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you describe more what you want to achieve?

It seems to me that [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) are made for this.